# Supremum of piecewise linear functions of integrable random variable is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have a sequence of piecewise linear functions $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function with $n$ linear components. Suppose $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ on every compact set i.e. compact convergence.

Now suppose we have an integrable random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ and assume $f(X)$ is integrable.

Is it true that $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} f_n(X)$ is also integrable?

Does there exist a function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $|\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} f_n(X)| \leq |g(X)|$ and $g(X)$ is integrable?

Is it true that $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} f_n(X)$ is integrable if we replace compact convergence with pointwise convergence and assuming  $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} f_n(x)$ is locally bounded?

Edit: My thoughts are that the above is true. We know that $f_n(X)$ is integrable for every $n$ since linear functions of integrable random variables are integrable. Since the limit $f(X)$ is also integrable and $f_n$ converges to it compactly, then $\sup f_n(X)$ should also be integrable. Otherwise, we have a contradiction that $f(X)$ is not integrable. Then if it is integrable, then there exists a function $g$ such that $|\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} f_n(X)| \leq |g(X)|$ and $g(X)$ is integrable.

Are my thoughts logical??? and would the same argument work for when  we replace compact convergence with pointwise convergence and assuming  $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} f_n(x)$ is locally bounded????